# Integral inequality, $f$ continuous, increasing function

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Let $f$ be a continuous, increasing  function on $[a,b]$, $c$ is the middle of $[a,b]$.

Prove that $\frac{f(a)+f(c)}{2} \le \frac{1}{b-a} \cdot \int _a ^b f(x)dx \le \frac{f(b)+f(c)}{2} $ .

Could you help me with that?

I thought I may use intermediate value theorem, but I didn't come up with anything.

Comment: 1) lower limit of integral is $a$, not 1.  2) Are you sure nothing about convexity stated in problem?

Comment: I've already corrected the limit. Thank you. There is no assumption about convexity of the function. We only know that it is continuous and increasing on the interval $[a,b]$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have
$$\int_a^b f(x)dx=\int_a^c f(x)dx+\int_c^b f(x)dx$$
and since $f$ is increasing function then
$$\int_a^cf(a)dx=\frac{f(a)(b-a)}{2}\leq\int_a^cf(x)dx\leq\int_a^cf(c)dx=\frac{f(c)(b-a)}{2}$$
and
$$\int_c^bf(c)dx=\frac{f(c)(b-a)}{2}\leq\int_c^bf(x)dx\leq\int_c^bf(b)dx=\frac{f(b)(b-a)}{2}$$
Now add the two inequalities.

Comment: $f(a)$ is a constant and $c$ is the middle of $[a,b]$ hence $c-a=\frac{b-a}{2}$ clear?

Comment: No  $c=\frac{a+b}{2}$.

Comment: All right :) Thank you a lot.

Comment: You're welcome.

Answer (score 3):

I assumed $c$ can be any point in $[a,b]$ hence this answer is incorrect.

I think $f$ has to be concave down.

Let's take $f(x)=x^2$ , which is concave up and see. To test take $c=b$ then $(f(a)+f(c))/2=(a^2+b^2)/2$ and $\int_a^b f(x)dx/(b-a)=(a^2+b^2+ab)/3$. Your inequality, on the left, would imply $(a^2+b^2)/2\le (a^2+b^2+ab)/3$ which upon simplification becomes $a^2+b^2\le 2ab$ which implies $(a-b)^2\le 0$.